# Create dynamic Google Map Markers with SVGs

Tags: vue.js, nuxt.js, nuxtjs

I am trying to create Google Map Markers with dynamic information in it. For that feature I am using a Vuejs-Component with a SVG as template and add a ["text"-Tag](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/SVG/Element/text).

Example:

```
<template>
    <svg width="40px" height="56px" viewBox="0 0 40 56" version="1.1" xmlns="http://www.w3.org/2000/svg"
         xmlns:xlink="http://www.w3.org/1999/xlink">
        <text>{{ text }}</text>
    </svg>
</template>

<script>
    export default {
        name: "DynamicGMapMarker",
        props: {
            text: {
                type: String,
                required: true
            }
        }
    }
</script>
```

Then I am creating the SVG via a helper function and create a base64 data url:

```
import Vue from 'vue'
import DynamicGMapMarker from './DynamicGMapMarker'

const DynamicGMapMarkerConstructor = Vue.extend(DynamicGMapMarker)

export const getDynamicMarkerIcon = (text) => {
    const iconComponent = new DynamicGMapMarkerConstructor({
        propsData: {
            text
        }
    });
    iconComponent.$mount();
    const iconDom = iconComponent.$el;
    const iconString = new XMLSerializer().serializeToString(iconDom);
    return 'data:image/svg+xml;charset=UTF-8;base64,' + btoa(iconString);
}
```

Now, I can use the `getDynamicMarkerIcon()` function. This is working in **vue.js**, but not in **nuxt.js**. In nuxt.js we need to add a XML-Serializer from npm, since nuxt can not use the Browser's XMLSerializer. For that I am using [teclone/xml-serializer](https://www.npmjs.com/package/@teclone/xml-serializer).

Now, the Problem seems to be that Nuxt can not create a DOM, because of SSR. When I am trying to use this method:

```
<template>
    <div id="app">
        <GmapMap
                :center="center"
                :zoom="15"
                :options="options"
                id="map"
        >
            <GmapCluster :zoomOnClick="true">
                <GmapMarker
                        :key="index"
                        v-for="(marker, index) in markers"
                        :position="marker.coordinates"
                        :clickable="true"
                        :draggable="false"
                        :title="marker.name"
                        :icon="getMarker(marker)"
                />
            </GmapCluster>
        </GmapMap>
    </div>
</template>

<script>
    import GmapCluster from 'vue2-google-maps/dist/components/cluster'
    import {getMarkerIcon} from "./MapIconUtil"

    export default {
        name: 'App',
        components: {
            GmapCluster
        },
        methods: {
            getMarker(marker) {
                return getDynamicMarkerIcon(marker.text);
            }
        },
        data() {
            return {
                options: {
                    zoomControl: false,
                    mapTypeControl: false,
                    scaleControl: false,
                    streetViewControl: false,
                    rotateControl: false,
                    fullscreenControl: false,
                    disableDefaultUi: true,
                    clickableIcons: false
                },
                center: {
                    lat: 11,
                    lng: 11
                },
                "markers": [
                    {
                        coordinates: {
                            name: "Test",
                            lat: 11.0001,
                            lng: 11.0001,
                            text: "101"
                        }
                    }
                ]
            }
        }
    }
</script>
```

I get an error that `iconComponent.$el` is undefined. I can not mount the SVG inside a DOM.

Are there any possibilities to tell Nuxt, that this component should run on browser side only?

I have already tried to wrap `GmapMarker` in `<client-only>`-Tag. That did not work. Can I use something like a "virtual DOM"? Any other ideas how to make it work?

Answer (score 0):

I did it. You can selectively change the "mode" in which nuxt will render a specific url. [Here you can see what configurations are possible.](https://nuxtjs.org/api/configuration-mode)

You have to create a server middleware and tell nuxt if a path should be rendered in **spa**. Otherwise just default to your mode specified in your **nuxt.config.js**.

[Check this out for an example.](https://blog.lichter.io/posts/nuxt-dynamic-ssr-spa-handling/)